# Redux dispatches an API call failure even though the network tab in devtools shows the API call received a status of 200

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux and I am having a hard time understanding how to connect the payload of my API call to my state.

Right now my action.js file looks like this:

```
import ApiService from '../../services/ApiService';
import { reset } from 'redux-form';

//actions
export const getStock = () => {
  return {
    type: 'GET_STOCK'
  }
}

export const getStockPending = () => {
  return {
    type: 'GET_STOCK_PENDING'
  }
}

export const getStockFulfilled = (stock) => {
  return {
    type: 'GET_STOCK_FULFILLED',
    payload: stock 
  }
}

export const getStockRejected = () => {
  return {
    type: 'GET_STOCK_REJECTED'
  }
}

// async function calls

export function fetchStocksWithRedux() {
  const action_type = "GET_STOCK";
  const stock = 'AAPL';
    return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: `${action_type}_PENDING`});
    return ApiService.get(`/search?query=${stock}`)
    .then(([response, json]) =>{
        if(response.status === 200){
        dispatch(getStockFulfilled(json))
      }
      else{
        dispatch(getStockRejected())
      }
    })
  }
}
```

and my reducer.js file looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
  inProgress: false,
  stock: {},
  stocks: ['NKE', 'AMZN', 'AAPL'],
  error: {}
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {

    case 'GET_STOCK_PENDING': 
      return {
        ...state, 
        inProgress: true,
        error: false
      }

    case 'GET_STOCK_FULFILLED': 
      return {
        ...state,
        stock: action.payload,
        inProgress: false
      }

    case 'GET_STOCK_REJECTED': 
      return {
        ...state,
        inProgress: false,
        error: action.error
      }
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

When I go to call my method fetchStocksWithRedux in my component, the network tab in my dev tools shows a 200 status and the response I'm expecting, but the reducer dispatches the 'GET_STOCK_REJECTED' action, but the error hash is empty. What do you think is going wrong?

Here is my component, for reference:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchStocksWithRedux } from '../../redux/modules/Stock/actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Dashboard extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
       this.props.fetchStocksWithRedux()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="uk-position-center">

            </div>
            )
        }
    }

export default connect(
  state => ({
    stocks: state.stocks,
    stock: state.stock
  })
  , { fetchStocksWithRedux }
)(Dashboard);
```

Thanks. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(response.status)`?

Comment: I guess your response.status is not 200 but 201. It returns the expected data but fails at if condition. That's why GET_STOCK_REJECTED is being called.

Comment: Hi - thanks so much to you both for responding. When I put console.log(response.status) I get a reference error that response is undefined. When I go to the network tab of the console however I see that the GET request to my API succeeded with a status 200 and I can read the response there. So somehow I am not passing the response in correctly in my API call?

Comment: I think you should check your `ApiService` module and make sure it work correctly. Also check the type of `response.status`, maybe it is a string